# Mod_rewrite creating seo friendly links but no database

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I am Totally newbie in this thing i have a website that doesn't use any database, link structure in my website look like this 
:
`http://telelivesports.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=150583&tv_id=985&tid=34429&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335`

i want to make this links seo friendly by using the page title(which will be team aA vs team B) instead of `?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=150583&tv_id=985&tid=34429&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335`

i want to know if this even possible without having any database
if yes how to do it

Comment: Why would you need a database?

Comment: The database is not the problem. You need to write a router that can consume the url and a mechanism to get the page based on info provided by that router.

Comment: @Bart any ideas about that mechanism that can use the url rovided above and use replace it with page title?

Comment: @daleNale How are you showing them now? You're url looks like a Joomla one.